# Can't start Android 4.2.2 emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I've tried to create a new emulator for Android 4.2.2 but it can't start at all, my setup like [this](http://grab.by/A3sY)

After I launch this emulator, lot's of Logcat errors show up and emulator never boot up. The error message like [this](http://grab.by/A3sm)

I've tried to increase RAM size and also turn off camera emulation option, etc, but it still doesn't work. If anyone has experience to resolve this problem, please help.

Comment: have you try to load with low resolution?

Comment: Try with another device. Maybe it is corrupted

Comment: Yes, tried 480x800, still the same error, wondering if something wrong with the system image of 4.2.2?

Comment: @helleye This is a newly created AVD. Still no good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Has far I know, never use more than 768MB of ram. Try to change it to 768MB or 512MB.

It solved my problem.